# What siddur is used by Reform communities in Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, prayer-book, reform-judaism

Understood, Reform Judaism is not as widespread in Israel as it is in America. Nevertheless, what siddur do Reform Jewish communities in Israel use? In America, Mishkan T'fila is popular (or the older Reform prayer book known as Gates of Prayer/Shaare T'fila). However this siddur is mostly English and it wouldn't make much sense for it to be used by Hebrew speaking communities. **What siddur is used by Reform Jewish communities in Israel?**

Comment: I suppose a significant percentage (if not the majority) of reform Jews in Israel are Anglos, therefore, it's possible that they use English books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there are actually Israeli Reform siddurim. The Israeli Reform Movement puts out two siddurim, an older version called [העבודה שבלב](https://www.beit-daniel.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91.pdf) and a more recent publication, [סידור תפילת האדם](https://www.reformjudaism.org.il/reform-sidur).